# Using ES5 .map with jQuery Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-5, map-function

How following code can use `ES5 .map` function, not jQuery .map?

```
        const newList = new Array();
        $(".something").each((_, opt2) => {
            const val2 = $(opt2).val();
            ddl2Vals.push(val2);
        })
```

I tried but fails:

```
const newList = $(".something").map(x => $(x).val());
```

**Edited to include class: it was typo.**

Comment: `$("#something")` this returns one Element!! what do you mean by `each` or `map`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume your real code uses a selector that returns more than one element (`#something` is an **ID selector**; IDs are supposed to be unique in the document).

As [prasanth said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68781653/157247), you can use `get` at the end to get a true array from the jQuery object, although you need to remember the difference between jQuery's [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) and Array's [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) (with jQuery's, the first argument to the callback is the index, not the element).

If you really want to use `Array`'s `map`, you can do that by using [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call), like this:

```
const newList = Array.prototype.map.call($("some-selector"), opt2 => $(opt2).val());
```

**But** ES2015 added `Array.from`, which can do mapping; see [Bergi's answer for details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68783237/157247) (the last code snippet).

---

Side note: If `opt2` is an `input`, `select`, or `option` element, there's no need to use jQuery to get its value:

```
const newList = Array.prototype.map.call($("some-selector"), opt2 => opt2.value);
```

or, again, with `Array.from` as Bergi pointed out:

```
const newList = Array.from($("some-selector"), opt2 => opt2.value);
```

Answer (score 2):

you could use `.get()` in last

```
$("#something").map((_, x) => $(x).val()).get()
```

Comment: Don't forget that the first argument passed to jQuery's [`map`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) is the index, not the item. I've taken the liberty of changing that in your answer, but if you're not happy with the change, please just hit rollback. :-)

Comment: I'd recommend to use [`.toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/) instead of `.get()`, it's more clear what it does

Comment: @Bergi yes correct  but its comes from `1.4`. But [`.get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/#get) comes from `1.0`. I learning from that things so i suggest. Thanks i will use it on future :-)

Answer (score 1):

To use the `map` method of `Array`, convert the jQuery collection to an array first using [`.toArray`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
const newList = $(".something").toArray().map(x => x.value);
```

Alternatively, you can use ES6 [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
const newList = Array.from($(".something")).map(x => x.value);
```

where you don't even need to use `.map()`, you can just use its second parameter to do the mapping and array conversion in just one step:

```
const newList = Array.from($(".something"), x => x.value);
```